# angularJS in Jquery function: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noDisagree' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to call AngularJs `controller` function with parameter in `Jquery` but get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noDisagree' of undefined

```
function noDisagree(id){
  var idToNg = parseInt(id);
  return angular.element('#voteChartsController').scope().noDisagree(idToNg);
}
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/nBvSGh?p=preview

Comment: can you create a plunker or fiddle for it? do you have the id voteChartsController in the html? plus what are you trying to achieve for that particular scope? with the function noDisagree?

Comment: Here is the Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/nBvSGh?p=preview

Comment: is your plunker complete, i don't see anything calling your noDisagree function.

Comment: The complete code is in the script.js

Comment: check my edited answer. I included a fiddle for you.

Comment: Thanks I've see your edit but would like to call not the ID element but the function and not on-click. I updated the plnkr issue...

Comment: Alex I did try your code and now it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: give me the plunkr of what you applied so far.

Comment: Here it is, you can also see it in plknr function noDisagree(id){
  var idToNg = parseInt(id);
  var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
  scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.msg = scope.noDisagree(idToNg);
    })
  

}

Comment: dude you don't have a div with an id of outer.

Comment: Just added it but does not help, still doing the same...

Comment: check the new answer. just what you wanted everything to your favour, tick it correct, its just at the left hand side of my start of answer.

Comment: Thanks again Alex but your updated code was like my initial one and here is what it and say again when I changed it to yours: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noDisagree' of undefined

Comment: dude i have given you the plunker, the second one which works. http://plnkr.co/edit/GAStnqcVN4I9hFiz32rT?p=preview. Just copy and paste the whole code. LOL. Come in chat room.

Comment: Alex the plunkr code works fine but it still does the same on my end Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noDisagree' of undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anywhere where you called the noDisagree function. So, i assumed and created a fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/rumba_alex47/w5vzm4n2/

**Update:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GAStnqcVN4I9hFiz32rT?p=preview

The final solution using `interPolateProvider`, just as you wanted :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-custom-interpolation-markup-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="customInterpolationApp">
  <script>
  var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

  customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
  });


  customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.issues = [{"id":"26","id_issue":"12"},{"id":"26","id_issue":"11"}];
    $scope.noDisagree = function(id_issue) {
      var count = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.issues.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.issues[i].id_issue == id_issue) {
            count++;
        }
      }
      return count;
    }
  });
  function noDisagree(id){
  var idToNg = parseInt(id);
  return angular.element('#DemoController').scope().noDisagree(idToNg);
} 

</script>
<div ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
    Here is the issue ID # <% noDisagree(11) %> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alex, I just gave it a try but unfortunately it does not fix it, here's my plunker link for this issue if you can do some workaround: https://plnkr.co/edit/nBvSGh?p=preview. Thank you very much!

Comment: check the fiddle i created https://jsfiddle.net/rumba_alex47/w5vzm4n2/   it has also been provided in the edited answer. Hope that is what you needed. If it is, then do upvote and tick it correct.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your post, but I wanted to just call the function automatically with no reference to any actions (without a click). I just updated the plnkr link and the function https://plnkr.co/edit/nBvSGh?p=preview

Comment: check the latest code. I am going to sleep. its 2:01 am here :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular directives or $scope must have noDisagree method in angular controller side

Comment: Do you have it attached to `this` or the prototype? If its just floating as a function there's no way its visible to the outside world. In addition, getting `scope().whatever` doesn't access controller functions.